# File Mapped in SBT Does not Get Copied to Classes Directory

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I'm using `xsbt-web-plugin` to create an exploded WAR file of a project containing both Java and Scala sources. The file is `src/main/java/conf/application.conf` and this is the way I believed would work:

```
webappWebInfClasses := true

// ...

mappings in (Compile, packageBin) += {
    ((javaSource in Compile).value / "conf" / "application.conf") -> "conf/application.conf"
}
```

When using `show compile:packageBin::mappings` in sbt, I see that the mapping is created correctly, but the file is never copied.

Note that `xsbt-web-plugin` goes over all of the files and manually copies them since `webappWebInfClasses` is set to `true`.

I'm using sbt 0.13.8, xsbt-web-plugin 2.0.2.

Comment: I would also appreciate any advice on how to debug an sbt build (add a breakpoint?) inside IntelliJ IDEA...

Comment: To debug an xsbt-web-plugin application, you can enable the standard Java remote debugging port via `javaOptions in Jetty ++= Seq("-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000")`.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny how it takes only a few minutes from putting it to writing to finding the issue. I was looking for the file in the `target/scala-2.11/classes` directory after running `compile`, when the scope is the WAR file itself.

Running `package` and extracting the WAR file showed the file where it was supposed to be.

Comment: The *classes/* directory (if any) included in the *.war* file by the `package` task can be found in *target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/* after running `webappPrepare`.